# Scrollable overlay

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

I'm using http://jquerytools.org overlay.
I've found here way to stop the page behind jquery tools overlay from scrolling and it's great until my element in overlay is not higher then my screen.
I know that it's possible because in http://pinterest.com it's working like I want. I was looking in their code, but was unable to understand how to make it.
Any real (simple) example how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I see on pininterest there is a "noscroll" class which is on the body:

```
    <body id="CategoriesBarPage" class="hidefixed noscroll" data-twttr-rendered="true">
```

"noscroll" uses overflow:hidden. I just tried this on the body tag on a demo on jsfiddle and it works.